# How to iterate to recent date folder present in aws s3 bucket where folders created based on date and dates are created in ascending order

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'd like to select date from recent `date` folder (e.g. `date` folders created from top to bottom as `01-01-2022` to `30-04-2023`).

Code should iterate from the `30-04-2023` to `01-01-2022` folder. I already tried listing more objects() and `collection.reverse()` but it is not helpful as it cannot load more than 1000 objects.

Appreciate your help! Thanks.

```py
ListObjectsResult a = client.listObjects("bucketname", "path to navigate to main Date folder");
                List<S3Object> b = a.getObjects();
                
                Adding moreobjects into list to get the more than 1000 keys
                while (a.isTruncated()) {
                    a = client.listMoreObjects(a);
                    b.addAll(a.getObjects());
                  //To get the list from the latest date
                  Collections.reverse(b);
                }
```